# jQuery - Update only works for one of many fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a form where if you update any of the inputs, it will update the sum. Right now only the first input is working. I want to use a single class across all of the inputs as the page is dynamic and the ID's can change often.

Here is the jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/6hukcp2a/)

Here is the code:

```
var productCost = function (input, output, changeOn) {
  var reloadCalcs = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(input).each(function() {     
      sum += parseFloat($(input).val());    
    }); 
    $(output).html(sum);
  };
  $(function () {
    $(changeOn).change(function () {
      reloadCalcs();
    });
    $(changeOn).trigger('change');             
  });
};

productCost('.product','.sum','input');
```

Comment: It's the name of the variable not the selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using

```
sum += parseFloat($(input).val());
```

You are telling the sum to add the value of `.product` to itself, since the `.product` selector will have multiple elements, it will choose the first one.
To fix this, you should use `this`:

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

Comment: On the money! Thanks and great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

2 changes

```js
var productCost = function(input, output, changeOn) {
  var reloadCalcs = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(input).each(function() {
      //use the value of current element
      sum += (+this.value || 0)
    });
    $(output).html(sum);
  };
  //use event delegation to support dynamic elements
  $(document).on('change', changeOn, function() {
    reloadCalcs();
  }).trigger('change');
};

productCost('.product', '.sum', 'input');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="product" id="design" value="5" />
<br>
<input type="number" class="product" id="features" value="5" />
<br>
<input type="number" class="product" id="performance" value="5" />
<br>
<input type="number" class="product" id="usability" value="5" />
<br>
<h3>TEST</h3>
<div class="sum"></div>
```

When you use `$(input).val()`, it will always return the value of the first input element instead of returning the value of current input in the loop